# What does question mark mean in the definition of function in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have got a function like this--

Function's name is seld.is_dl and it is accepting path parameter. My question is that what does this `?` sign in the function definition indicate.

```
def self.is_dl?(path)

  path = File.basename(path)

  if path =~ /setup.exe/i

    return false

  else

    return true

  end

end
```

I am java developer and I have seen "?" in case of If-ELSE block mainly, that is why I am not able to figure what does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?` is a valid character in a method name.

It is typically used to denote a method that returns `true` or `false`

For example:

- [File.exists?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-exist-3F)
- [File.readable?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-readable-3F)
- [String#ascii_only?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ascii_only-3F)
- etc

Note: `!` is also a valid character. It is typically used to denote a "destructive" method

- [String#capitalize!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21)
- [String#downcase!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-downcase-21)
- [String#rstrip!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip-21)
- etc

---

If you're feeling like going the extra mile, Ruby technically allows any string to be a method name. Odd ones need `define_method()` and `send()` calls, but formally there’s no restriction.

```
module Hello

  class << self
    define_method "this is my method :)" do |foo|
      puts "you gave my method #{foo}"
    end

    define_method "this isn't your method :(, sorry" do
      puts "sorry, not your method, bro"
    end
  end

end

Hello.send("this is my method :)", "candy")
#=> you gave my method candy

Hello.send("this isn't your method :(, sorry")
#=> sorry, not your method, bro
```

Comment: Also, `#method?` shouldn't have any side-effects. And the bang (`!`, you say "sort bang" for `Array#sort!`) denotes a method with which you should be careful (not necessarily destructive).

Comment: it **is** destructive. it destroys (alters) the original array that it was called upon.